# SUPEE-11086 hunk FAILED

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.3.8, supee-11086

i'm trying to apply supee-11086 patch and getting following error:

```
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Api/Buttons.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Buttons.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Design/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Store/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Email/PathValidator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 69.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Gatewayurl.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Protected.php
```

Magento version 1.9.3.8. I already try download clean 1.9.3.8 and replace this file, but nothing changed. How can i solve it?

Comment: So whether did you applied this patch PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.3.10_v1.sh

Comment: @RajMohanR nope, getting this error

Comment: Can you say the patch file name which you have applied? So you are using 1.9.3.8 so download the patch for the version 1.9.3.10 and apply it. Please visit https://magento.com/tech-resources/download, download the PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.3.10_v1.sh and try to apply this patch. Please try this and say what happens.

Comment: @RajMohanR i tried with 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.10 - not solve. I already found and post the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found.

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 69. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
```

This file has old code, i replaced this file with more new version(1.9.3.10) and apply patch.